# php getting values used after dot

Tags: php

Is there a way to make php make this piece of code:

```
myclass.randomthingwrittenhere
```

work as

```
myclass.nexttodotoperator(randomthingwrittenhere)?
```

I want to write my own database framework to databases and im wondering if it can work somehow.

Comment: "this piece of code" --- what language is it?

Comment: @zerkms - question title says php

Comment: @Boofus McGoofus: I hardly doubt `myclass.randomthingwrittenhere` - is a valid php code.

Comment: I've been working in too many different languages lately to catch both the .s and the lack of $s.  That said, I suspect you can let cats dance on your keyboard and end up with valid php.

Comment: @boofus: that's perl. php will just trash your database with kitten-induced sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Accessing members on objects?

I'm really not sure what you're doing in your example. When you access properties or call methods on objects you use the `->` syntax, unlike JavaScript which can use `.`.

There are a few *magic methods* that you can add to your class to handle this:

```
class MyClass {
    function __get ( $property ) {
        $this->something( $property );
    }
    function __call ( $method, $arguments ) {
        $this->something( $method, $arguments );
    }
}
```

In this code, any instance of the class will let you handle requests for members that aren't found on the instance itself.

Demo: http://codepad.org/3qB8gXfv

#### String manipulation?

That being said, perhaps you're not asking about classes at all, but instead string manipulation. If I understand your question correctly, provide your input string:

```
$string = "myclass.randomthingwrittenhere";
```

Then split up the two parts into your class, and your method:

```
list($class, $method) = explode(".", $string);
```

Then spit out the new string, interpolating the variables:

```
echo "$class.foobar($method)";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/vggOIA9U

Comment: __get func will just do well. I wanted just user to feel like accesing real values from virtual class representing row from db.

Comment: @oneat You should be able to use that then. WordPress does some of this internally I believe. If a property is requested, but not found on the object, it makes a trip to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at "magic methods" in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

In your case, you can write a function like this...

```
function __get($name) {
   return this->nexttodooperator($name); 
}
```